# How to implement SSE (Server Sent Events) server and client in Python?

Tags: python, server, client, server-sent-events, web-of-things

I need to implement both an SSE server and client in Python to be able to send to the clients events anytime i want after the client subscribed to it.
Specifically i have an API made with Flask in the server, the client should be able to subscribe to the event channel by sending a GET to that API.

I already found implementations of the SSE client in Python online and that shouldn't be a problem, but i can't find the server-side implementation. I can find just the Javascript implementation for the server.

Comment: Since you have put web-of-things, are you looking into how sse looks like in TDs?

Comment: Nope, i'm trying to implement the /events API of the Thing Description Directory using SSE. My bad, i forgot to specify that in the question.

Comment: I am not sure if you are trying to do a proof of concept or a product level implementation but I have found this https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-sse . Sadly it is dependent on redis but it should be ok for a PoC?

Answer (score 3):

I have done some more research and talking with others. First of all, make sure to always search for EventSource since that is what the HTML5 spec call it.

You can find one at https://pythonhosted.org/eventsource/ and a more guided way on how to implement it at https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56

In the end, all you have to do is keep the HTTP connection open.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't answer you, but at the end i solved by using sseclient in Python and creating a Thread for every connection i made and kept it up.

It's for my degree by the way, as i was working on developing a functional TD Directory. Now i'm writing the thesis on it as i finished it.

You helped me a lot even with the other question about validation, so thank you very much!

Comment: No problem at all :)